# ng build --prod takes forever

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I am a DevOps engineer and I build a CI pipeline for our Angular project.
Unfortunately, the build takes over 10 mintues! while over 100 builds performed per day by our developers.
The ng build performed using the following flags: --prod --aot=true --optimization=true and it takes over 10 minutes.
While I build it with --optimization=false --aot=false --sourceMap=false it takes less than a mintue but we need it with prod configuration so I can't ignore those flags.
I read a lot about the ng build process and I couldn't find any solution to decrease the build time.
I raised the --max-old-space-size to 32gb of ram, I tried change the node_module relative path to ~ instead of /../../ and I tried every single way I found for trying to solve it but it didn't work.
I know ng build is a single threaded, there is realy no way to run the build in parallel?
This thing really impact our total build time and I have to find a way to solve that issue, does anyone of you had the same issue and succeeded to solve the build time issue?